# Why is dev_appserver.py reporting "no such file or directory" after today's gcloud components update

Tags: google-app-engine

I've been successfully running the local development server daily and have made no changes except that I called "gcloud components update" just before it stopped working.  Now I get:

```
..snip...    <<PATH TO MY SDK>>/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 518, in _parse_configuration
        with open(configuration_path) as f:
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'app.yaml'
```

Of course app.yaml hasn't moved.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Note:  As a workaround, if I specify the full path to app.yaml when running dev_appserver.py it works.  I'm confused why I would suddenly have to start doing this though.

Comment: Expanding on the above workaround -  it is good to do so in the command line, but if you work with PyCharm, and use App Engine server configuraiton, just add the full path to "Additional options". Just the full path to your app.yaml.

e.g. `C:\myprojects\project1\app.yaml`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like there's [an active issue on Google's issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/117145272) (opened on Oct 2, 2018) pertaining to this:

> After updating to the Python (2.7) extensions for GAE to version
> 1.9.76, I am no longer able to run my code with dev_appserver.py

As of Oct 3, a fix appears to be in the works, but for now they suggest downgrading Google Cloud SDK to version 218.0.0:

> It seems like you are affected by a known issue regarding ‘dev_appserver.py’ breaks in Google Cloud SDK version [219.0.1]. App Engine specialists are currently working to resolve it. However
> there is no ETA at this moment. As a workaround you can downgrade the
> Google Cloud SDK version using this command:

```
gcloud components update --version 218.0.0
```

The assignee of the issue will post an update on that issue when it has been resolved.

**UPDATE (OCT 9, 2018):** Cloud SDK version 220.0.0, which fixes the dev_appserver.py issue, is now available. I updated (via `gcloud components update`) and verified that it works. (Note: there are already a couple of complaints on the Issue Tracker that dev_appserver.py takes too long to load now. I didn't notice a significant difference from version 218, but I didn't compare timings.)

Comment: This worked for me. I had updated to Mojave on Mac along with updating components so it was extra confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You may create `make` file and have something like this:

```
export SDK=dev_appserver.py
export APP_PATH=${CURDIR}

run:
    $(SDK) $(APP_PATH)/path-to/app.yaml
```

And just use it with: `make run` so you don't have to worry about paths.

Answer (score 0):

`cd` to the directory with `app.yaml` in it and try again

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, `dev_appserver.py %CD%` is enough if your .yaml file has the default `app.yaml` name. Otherwise `dev_appserver.py %CD%/your-file-name.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: in `app.yaml`, change

`runtime: go`

to

`runtime: go111`