# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'app.yaml'

Tags: google-app-engine

My computer shut off during a power outage while my sever was running. Everything was working fine before, but when I turned my computer back on and tried to restart the server, I get the below error. I tried reinstalling the Google SDK and `--support_datastore_emulator=False` and launching other apps I have, but nothing works. The app.yaml file definitely exists in the directory and it worked fine before the computer shut off.

```
Nicks-iMac:data nick$ dev_appserver.py app.yaml INFO     2018-10-07 15:05:32,499 devappserver2.py:224] Using Cloud Datastore Emulator. We are gradually rolling out the emulator as the default datastore implementation of dev_appserver. If broken, you can temporarily disable it by --support_datastore_emulator=False Read the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/migrate-cloud-datastore-emulator Report issues at: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187272


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nick/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 96, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/Users/nick/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 90, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/Users/nick/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 617, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/nick/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 605, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/Users/nick/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 266, in start
    env_variables=parsed_env_variables)
  File "/Users/nick/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 957, in __init__
    env_variables)
  File "/Users/nick/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 140, in __init__
    self._config_path)
  File "/Users/nick/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 518, in _parse_configuration
    with open(configuration_path) as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'app.yaml'
```

Comment: Check if the `app.yaml` file still exists (it's possible it was lost if the filesystem was corrupted). Run the command from the directory where the `app.yaml` file exists - often after reboot or when opening a new terminal one forgets to `cd` into that directory.  Or specify the full path to the `app.yaml` file.

Comment: Also potentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52656893/4495081